# How stop method remembering previous variable value in turn-based game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script controls the enemy's movement in a turn-based game. I have a problem: Basically my script remembers the previous turn's randomAttack value. It shows correctly in the debug log, but the execution is slow. The character would move into a melee attack just like in the previous turn, but then stops for a range attack.

```
private int randomAttack;
private bool enableAction;

public void BeginTurn()
{
    if (GameManagerPVE.instance.curPlayer == enemy) 
    {
        randomAttack = Random.Range(0, 1 + 1);
        enableAction = true;
    } 
}


IEnumerator EndTurn()
{
    GameManagerPVE.instance.SetNextTurn(2);
    yield return null;
}


void Update() 
{
    if(enableAction == true)
    {
        if(randomAttack == 0)
            StartCoroutine(MeleeAttack());
        else
            StartCoroutine(RangeAttack());
    }
}
```

Comment: have a method you call at the start of begin turn that resets all the things you need to reset to a default? hard to know looking at the little code youve shared and little info you gave us

Comment: I added randomAttack = null at the top of BeginTurn, but I'm still having the same problem. It basically saves 0 somewhere in memory even when its 1 and does both

Comment: @BugFinder that comment was already given to the same question yesterday (presumably asked by the same person)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did quickly look didnt find the question on this account, so I assumed this is a different one.. but it wouldnt surprise me to find it deleted and this is the same person same question

Comment: `randoimAttack` isnt quite a 'local variable if it is defined outside the method

Comment: wait, you can set int to null @jsmith?

Comment: Your description of the issue sounds a bit like there are concurrent Coroutines running both trying to do their thing and competing against each other ... Very hard to tell without seeing a [mcve] of your code .. the bit you show here is not enough to reproduce the issue .. For instance I wonder why pool check a flag in `Update` instead of right away starting the according coroutine **ONCE** within `BeginTurn` reducing the potential issue that `enableAction` is not or to late set to `false`

Comment: Thanks I understand. I will try and add more code later, am currently at work. The reason for that is that I'm running the melee attack's movement through update using movetowards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my MeleeAttack coroutine, I needed an if condition inside the while loop.

```
IEnumerator MeleeAttack()
{
while (transform.position != targetPos)
            {
                if (randomAttack == 0)
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, 0.3f * Time.deltaTime);
                }
       yield return null;        
            }
yield return null;
}
```